# Error in running jar file of spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, docker, devops

When i create a jar file it will be created but when i run a jar file it will show error similar happened with docker file when i create a docker file it will be created but when i run a docker file it will show error.

```
jar {
    baseName = "${project.jarName}"
    version = "${project.versionName}"
    enabled = true
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.exmaple.Application'
    }

}


task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: build) {
    push = false
    applicationName = jar.baseName
    tagVersion = jar.version
    dockerfile = file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')
    doFirst {
        copy {
            from jar
            into stageDir
        }
        copy {
            from "${project.buildDir}/resources/main/run.sh"
            into stageDir
        }
    }
}
```

> ERROR.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
    at com.example.Application.main(Application.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication

Comment: What does your Dockerfile look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Shadow Jar library in build.gradle file to resolve this issue.

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.1'
```